# Is it possible to scan a network for connected devices and list them in the program?

Tags: vb.net

I have this question for you.

Is it possible? I have an app on my android phone that can list all connected ips and get information about them such as: Device name, mac-adress.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. I wrote a class for that years ago tho I don't know if it will detect networked drives. Look on vbforums in the codebank fora drive class or look for SpYk3

Comment: Ill be at a pc shortly I can look it up

Answer (score 0):

I found [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using) in order to browse my network a few weeks back and it worked pretty well for me. Here is the VB conversion :

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace ListNetworkComputers
    #Region "NetworkBrowser CLASS"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Provides a mechanism for supplying
    ' a list of all PC names in the local network.
    ''' This collection of PC names is used in the form 
    ''' 


''' This class makes use of a DllImport instruction.
''' The purpose of which is as follows:
''' When a DllImport declaration is made
''' in managed code (C#) it is a call to a legacy
''' unmanaged code module, normally
''' a C++ Dynamic Link Library. These C++ Dll's are
''' usually part of the operating system API,
''' or some other vendors API, and must be 
''' used to carry out operations that are not
''' native within the managed code C# framework. 
''' This is fairly normal within the windows world.
''' The only thing that needs careful consideration
''' is the construction of the correct type of STRUCTS,
''' object pointers, and attribute markers,
''' which all contribute to making the link
''' between managed (C#) and unmanaged code (C++)
''' more seamless
''' 

''' This class makes use of the following Dll calls
''' <list type="bullet">
''' <item>
''' <description> Netapi32.dll : NetServerEnum,
''' The NetServerEnum function lists all servers
''' of the specified type that are visible in
''' a domain. For example, an application can call 
''' NetServerEnum to list all domain controllers
''' only or all SQL servers only.
''' You can combine bit masks to list several
''' types. For example, a value of 0x00000003 
''' combines the bit masks for SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION
''' (0x00000001) and SV_TYPE_SERVER (0x00000002).
''' </description>
''' </item>
''' <item>
''' <description> Netapi32.dll : NetApiBufferFree,
''' The NetApiBufferFree function frees 
''' the memory that the NetApiBufferAllocate
''' function allocates. Call NetApiBufferFree 
''' to free the memory that other network
''' management functions return.</description>
''' </item>
''' </list>
''' </summary>
Public NotInheritable Class NetworkBrowser
    #Region "Dll Imports"

    'declare the Netapi32 : NetServerEnum method import

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Netapi32.dll : The NetServerEnum function lists all servers
    ''' of the specified type that are
    ''' visible in a domain. For example, an 
    ''' application can call NetServerEnum
    ''' to list all domain controllers only
    ''' or all SQL servers only.
    ''' You can combine bit masks to list
    ''' several types. For example, a value 
    ''' of 0x00000003  combines the bit
    ''' masks for SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION 
    ''' (0x00000001) and SV_TYPE_SERVER (0x00000002)
    ''' </summary>
    ' must be null
    ' null for login domain
    <DllImport("Netapi32", CharSet := CharSet.Auto, SetLastError := True), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute> _
    Public Shared Function NetServerEnum(ServerNane As String, dwLevel As Integer, ByRef pBuf As IntPtr, dwPrefMaxLen As Integer, ByRef dwEntriesRead As Integer, ByRef dwTotalEntries As Integer, _
        dwServerType As Integer, domain As String, ByRef dwResumeHandle As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    'declare the Netapi32 : NetApiBufferFree method import

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Netapi32.dll : The NetApiBufferFree function frees 
    ''' the memory that the NetApiBufferAllocate function allocates. 
    ''' Call NetApiBufferFree to free
    ''' the memory that other network 
    ''' management functions return.
    ''' </summary>
    <DllImport("Netapi32", SetLastError := True), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute> _
    Public Shared Function NetApiBufferFree(pBuf As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    'create a _SERVER_INFO_100 STRUCTURE
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure _SERVER_INFO_100
        Friend sv100_platform_id As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
        Friend sv100_name As String
    End Structure
    #End Region
    #Region "Public Constructor"
    ''' <SUMMARY>
    ''' Constructor, simply creates a new NetworkBrowser object
    ''' </SUMMARY>

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    #End Region
    #Region "Public Methods"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Uses the DllImport : NetServerEnum
    ''' with all its required parameters
    ''' (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?
    '''      url=/library/en-us/netmgmt/netmgmt/netserverenum.asp
    ''' for full details or method signature) to
    ''' retrieve a list of domain SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION
    ''' and SV_TYPE_SERVER PC's
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>Arraylist that represents
    ''' all the SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION and SV_TYPE_SERVER
    ''' PC's in the Domain</returns>
    Public Function getNetworkComputers() As ArrayList
        'local fields
        Dim networkComputers As New ArrayList()
        Const  MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH As Integer = -1
        Dim SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION As Integer = 1
        Dim SV_TYPE_SERVER As Integer = 2
        Dim buffer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim tmpBuffer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim entriesRead As Integer = 0
        Dim totalEntries As Integer = 0
        Dim resHandle As Integer = 0
        Dim sizeofINFO As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(_SERVER_INFO_100))


        Try
            'call the DllImport : NetServerEnum 
            'with all its required parameters
            'see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/
            'default.asp?url=/library/en-us/netmgmt/netmgmt/netserverenum.asp
            'for full details of method signature
            Dim ret As Integer = NetServerEnum(Nothing, 100, buffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, entriesRead, totalEntries, _
                SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION Or SV_TYPE_SERVER, Nothing, resHandle)
            'if the returned with a NERR_Success 
            '(C++ term), =0 for C#
            If ret = 0 Then
                'loop through all SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION 
                'and SV_TYPE_SERVER PC's
                For i As Integer = 0 To totalEntries - 1
                    'get pointer to, Pointer to the 
                    'buffer that received the data from
                    'the call to NetServerEnum. 
                    'Must ensure to use correct size of 
                    'STRUCTURE to ensure correct 
                    'location in memory is pointed to
                    tmpBuffer = New IntPtr(CInt(buffer) + (i * sizeofINFO))
                    'Have now got a pointer to the list 
                    'of SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION and 
                    'SV_TYPE_SERVER PC's, which is unmanaged memory
                    'Needs to Marshal data from an 
                    'unmanaged block of memory to a 
                    'managed object, again using 
                    'STRUCTURE to ensure the correct data
                    'is marshalled 
                    Dim svrInfo As _SERVER_INFO_100 = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer, GetType(_SERVER_INFO_100)), _SERVER_INFO_100)

                    'add the PC names to the ArrayList
                    networkComputers.Add(svrInfo.sv100_name)
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with acessing " + "network computers in NetworkBrowser " + vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            'The NetApiBufferFree function frees 
            'the memory that the 
            'NetApiBufferAllocate function allocates
            NetApiBufferFree(buffer)
        End Try
        'return entries found
        Return networkComputers

    End Function
    #End Region
End Class
#End Region
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, I wrote this years ago and it worked great. Code probably needs a bit of an "advanced" update as I wrote it as a novice to vb.net, but as I said, it worked great. It was used in law enforcement custom made pc's, so ...

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?604857-VB2008-USB-CDRom-Harddrive-Network-drive-find-state-amp-more-Class!

100% VB.Net

---

To answer your comment, as I said, I wrote this years ago, and it could use some updating I'm sure. The use is outlined in the forum, but I'll reiterate with more detail.

The zip file includes the entire project. This means you can simply extract it to your VS projects folder, and open it up to look at examples of it's use. The library itself, as I see, was built on an F5 debug, thus it already exist in the directory `Driver Detective\bin\Debug`, tho you could run the program full and get the same file from `bin\Release`.

The file you will need is `Drive Detective.dll`. I don't remember (it's been a while) the whole process, but move that file to somewhere you can easily locate, or just make note of where it is in the `Debug` directory. Open the project you'd like to use it in, add it to your library list. Like I said, been a long time since I've used VS, so I don't remember what that process is called, but basically, add the lib to your project so you can use it as such:

```
Imports driver Detective.driver Detective
Private Sub myForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load '<- this obviously a window load event
    meClass = New driverDetective(Me.Handle)
    Dim test As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = meClass.findDrives(DriveType.CDRom) 'this will find any and all connected CDRom's
```

The previous shows how to find all connected drives of type CDRom. This is just one of many uses. It contains only a few public functions that get straight to the "needs" of dealing with drive detection. It's strength is in its events. Once added and you make your handler (`meClass = New driverDetective(Me.Handle)`), you find you suddenly have a full event driven class for dealing with drive detection.

### The Public Methods

- findDrives: Attempts to find all drives of a select type on system and return values in Dictionary Lists to provide full drive information for each found
- byteConverter: Converts **`Long`** Byte values to Compact forms like 1024Bytes = 1kB
- getPercentage: Does just that, plug in small # and large # and get result
- getTB, getGB, getMB, getKB, getBytes: Should be kind obvious here

### Events

- connected_CDRom, connected_Fixed, connected_Network, connected_NoRootDirectory, connected_Ram, connected_Removable, connected_Unknown: Events for detecting connection of the Drive Type stated in event method name.
- removed_CDRom, removed_Removable: For whatever reason, disconnect is not as divided. I'm guessing most devices have same exit strat
- Long list of Error events I used for testing, still in there for your own use

Was able to dig up a VS at work and run it once and check, as you can see, it does work for detecting Network drives.
[image]

Comment: Hello, I don't get how you use this? Could you please explain?